# detect socket timeout when using "with" instead of "try"

Tags: python

Using python 3.6.8, I have the following code

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.settimeout(20)
    s.connect(host, port)
```

As I understand it, using `with` as shown instead of a `try` `except` block better handles the error condition that occurs if opening the socket (`s.connect()`) fails. How so? In the code as shown, if `s.connect()` times out, will it print a message? My main question is, can I detect that it timed out, e.g. to run some code if a timeout occurs? I want to be able to do that from within the `with` block without using `try`. I read this example

```
with opened_w_error("/etc/passwd", "a") as (f, err):
    if err:
        print "IOError:", err
    else:
        f.write("guido::0:0::/:/bin/sh\n")
```

But that doesn't detect the type of error. I read this as well

```
try:
    with ContextManager():
        BLOCK
except InitError:  # raised from __init__
    ...
except AcquireResourceError:  # raised from __enter__
    ...
except ValueError:  # raised from BLOCK
    ...
except ReleaseResourceError:  # raised from __exit__
```

But I'm hoping there is a way to detect if it's a timeout error from within the `with` block.

Comment: The context manager doesn't handle any errors; it just ensures `s.close()` gets called when possible.

Comment: Basically `try: s = socket.socket(...); ...; finally: s.close()`. If you want to catch any other errors, you need your own `try` statement.

Comment: There may be a way using "contextlib.ExitStack" but the resulting code will be uglier than an additional try-block and provides less functionality.